# Authorization Failed while making GET Request to Azure Blob Storage [REST API][Azure Blob Storage]

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication

I am trying to make a GET request to get Account details of my Azure Blob Storage account, but it shows Auth failed each and every time.
Can anyone tell whether the Header or Signature String formed is correct or is there any other issue?

**Here's the code:**

```
const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const key = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY || "";

var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();
var strToSign =
  "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" +
  strTime +
  `\nx-ms-version:2018-03-28\n/${account}/\ncomp:properties\nrestype:account`;
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = `SharedKey ${account}:${hashInBase64}`;

const options = {
  url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=properties&restype=account`,

  headers: {
    Authorization: auth,
    "x-ms-date": strTime,
    "x-ms-version": "2018-03-28",
  },
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  var json = parser.toJson(body);
  console.log(error);
  console.log(response);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var json = parser.toJson(body);
    console.log(json);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

After this, the response.statusCode which I am getting is Status 403.

```
statusCode: 403,
statusMessage: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.',
```

The details about the azure-blob and headers and Auth could be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-account-information

EDIT:
**The string param `=` has been corrected to `:`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be much easier [using Azure Storage JS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs) to make requests to Azure Blob Storage. If you want to get your storage account information, just try code below:

```
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const account = '<storage account name>'
const accountKey = '<storage account key>'

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    sharedKeyCredential
);

blobServiceClient.getAccountInfo().then((result)=>{
    console.log("accountKind:"+result.accountKind + " skuName:" + result.skuName + " version:" + result.version );
})
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to try it in a more generic fashion, try the code below:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var request = require("request");
var parser = require('body-parser')

const account = ''
const key = ''

var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();
var strToSign =
  "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" +
  strTime +
  `\nx-ms-version:2018-03-28\n/${account}/\ncomp:properties\nrestype:account`;

  //console.log(strToSign);
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = `SharedKey ${account}:${hashInBase64}`;

const options = {
  url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=properties&restype=account`,

  headers: {
    Authorization: auth,
    "x-ms-date": strTime,
    "x-ms-version": "2018-03-28",
  },
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
 
  console.log(body);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    console.log(response.headers["x-ms-sku-name"]);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Result:

[image]

Seems you should use `:` instead of `=` in last param of your `strToSign` .

Comment: Yes, I have tried it using Azure Storage SDK and it works but I want to try it in a more generic fashion. Thus cant use Azure SDK. Thanks.

Comment: @MayankPatel, I have updated my answer, if it is helpful for you, could you please click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks, @Stanley seems that the problem for Get Account Information was solved.
But I have ran into another issue, for Get Container Details.
 The resource string which I am using is:
var strToSign =
  "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" +
  strTime +
  `\nx-ms-version:2018-03-28\n/${account}/demo?restype:container`;
and url is : `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/demo?restype=container`

is there something crucial that I am missing.

Comment: @MayankPatel, could you please open a new question and let me know the link for it ?

Comment: Hi, That problem was resolved presently I am stuck on another problem related to uploading data as a stream to azure blob using REST API. Here's the link to the problem please have a look. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468944/upload-a-stream-to-azure-blob-storage-using-rest-api-without-azure-sdk/66469562?noredirect=1#comment117510209_66469562)