# Upload a Stream to Azure Blob Storage using REST API without Azure SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, rest

I wish to upload files in the form of a stream into **Azure Storage** but I don't want to use `Azure SDK` instead I want to do it in a more generic way using `REST API` and **not** `BlobServiceClient`.

Is there a way to do so?
The reference links for the same can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-javascript?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#blob-samples

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/advanced.js#L74

But the links mentioned here propose a solution using `Azure SDK`. I want to do it **without** `Azure SDK`

**Here's the code:**

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const request = require("request");
const fs = require("fs");

const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const key = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY || "";
const containerName = "demo";
const blobName = "dummyfile.txt";
var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();

// read file to Stream
var filePath = `${__dirname}/README.md`;
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

string_params = {
  verb: "PUT",
  "Content-Encoding": "",
  "Content-Language": "",
  "Content-Length": stat.size,
  "Content-MD5": "",
  "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
  Date: "",
  "If-Modified-Since": "",
  "If-Match": "",
  "If-None-Match": "",
  "If-Unmodified-Since": "",
  Range: "",
  CanonicalizedHeaders:
    "x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:" +
    strTime +
    "\nx-ms-version:" +
    "2020-04-08\n",
  CanonicalizedResource: `/${account}/${containerName}/${blobName}`,
};

var strToSign = `${string_params["verb"]}\n${string_params["Content-Encoding"]}\n${string_params["Content-Language"]}\n${string_params["Content-Length"]}\n${string_params["Content-MD5"]}\n${string_params["Content-Type"]}\n${string_params["Date"]}\n${string_params["If-Modified-Since"]}\n${string_params["If-Match"]}\n${string_params["If-None-Match"]}\n${string_params["If-Unmodified-Since"]}\n${string_params["Range"]}\n${string_params["CanonicalizedHeaders"]}${string_params["CanonicalizedResource"]}`;

var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = `SharedKey ${account}:` + hashInBase64;

const options = {
  url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: auth,
    "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
    "x-ms-date": strTime,
    "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Content-Length": stat.size,
  },
  body: readStream,
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.statusMessage);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
  }
}

request.put(options, callback);
```

The error which I am getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

**Edit: The problem was solved by Pamela's code + the issue I found was there's was an error in initializing `.env` variables.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) Rest API to upload a stream. There is a sample using node.js.

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const request = require("request");
const fs = require('fs');

const account = "account-name";
const key = "account-key";
var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();

var filePath = 'your-file-path';
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

string_params = {
    'verb': 'PUT',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': stat.size,
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:' + strTime + '\nx-ms-version:' + '2020-04-08\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': `/${account}/containername/myblob`
}


var strToSign = `${string_params['verb']}\n${string_params['Content-Encoding']}\n${string_params['Content-Language']}\n${string_params['Content-Length']}\n${string_params['Content-MD5']}\n${string_params['Content-Type']}\n${string_params['Date']}\n${string_params['If-Modified-Since']}\n${string_params['If-Match']}\n${string_params['If-None-Match']}\n${string_params['If-Unmodified-Since']}\n${string_params['Range']}\n${string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']}${string_params['CanonicalizedResource']}`
console.log(strToSign);

var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = `SharedKey ${account}:` + hashInBase64;
console.log(auth)

const options = {
    url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/containername/myblob`,
    headers: {
        Authorization: auth,
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        "x-ms-date": strTime,
        "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
        'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream",
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    },
    body: readStream
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.statusMessage);
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request.put(options, callback);
```

Comment: Hi Pamela, I have already tried the solution that you mentioned but I am looking for a solution to upload data as a stream and not as a whole directly. Still Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you mean upload stream of a file to azure blob?

Comment: Yes, upload pdfs, jpegs, JSON, text files as a stream of data.

Comment: You could read the file as stream, and set `Content-Type` as `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: I tried what you meant but still facing issues, here's the code link [link](https://pastecode.io/s/hi59m815eE). Can you help resolve the issue?

Comment: `Content-Length` is required. You could compare yours with my code.

Comment: you mentioned body field in options as "s", but s hasn't been declared anywhere. 
Also you didn't make use of readStream that you made, can you please review it. 
Also, how can I know the content length if I am reading a file in form of a stream?

Comment: Yes, it's readStream, I forgot to modify it. Try get length with `var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
console.log(stat.size)`. I will edit the answer with whole code.

Comment: I have uploaded the code along with the error and screenshot to error in the Question above please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Azure REST API for the Blob Operations. You can find REST API's for Blob here - [Operations on Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/operations-on-blobs)

The question is how are you going to handle stream upload at runtime. Azure SDK supports the stream upload. However in case of REST API, you'll need to handle that by yourself.

Uploading stream or parallel data you'll need some wrapper around this REST API Calls to achieve that

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Hi Abhi, I don't completely get what you meant to say. Here's the code [link](https://pastecode.io/s/hi59m815eE). can you see where the issue lies?